# When using nested tabs with jqueryui, how can you catch events from only the parent widget

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using the jqueryui widget, [tabs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/). I'm in a situation where I have tab nested within tabs.
I want to handle events from the parent tabs widget only (#tabs) but ignore the nested child (#tabs2). Is this possible?

**[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NzcJd/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="fragment-1">
    1st
    <div id="tabs2">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#fragment2-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment2-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="fragment2-1">
        1st
      </div>
      <div id="fragment2-2">
        2nd
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="fragment-2">
    2nd
  </div>
</div>

<div id="debug"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$( "#tabs" ).on( "tabsactivate", function( event, ui ) {

    // This code will execute whether the event came from #tabs or #tabs2

    $("#debug").text("Activated tab " + ui.newPanel.selector);
} );
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since child element is firing the same event, you need to filter event coming from the child.
It can be done in this way:

```
$("#tabs" ).on("tabsactivate", function( event, ui ) {
    if(this !== event.target)
    {
        return false;
    }
    $("#debug").text("Activated tab " + ui.newPanel.selector);
});
```

Here is a sample fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/nQsDK/4/